# Complexity analysis of a method

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

Need to analyze the complexity of recursive function. The function is below.

```
int hello(int n){
   if(n==0)
       return 0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n * n;j++){
         System.out.println("HELLO");
      }
   }
   return hello(n-1);
}
```

The step that I am confused is hello(n-1). I don't know how to evaluate a complexity like that code. If you tell the solution of that question step by step, I would be really appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are there two loops both defining i? Without the recursion the method may be O(n^2), with the recursion it is basically O(n^2 + (n-1)^2 + (n-2)^2 + …) which you need to simplify.

Comment: Thank you for your notice @luk2302. I have edit the loop. Please check it.

Comment: Okay, now it is ^3 instead of ^2 in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the running time of a recursive function is denoted by T(n) where n is the size of the input. In recurrence relation, the running time of a recursive function of input size n is expressed in terms of the running time of the lower value of n. In your case

T(n) = T(n-1) + n^3   (nested for loops run for O(n^3))

= T(n-2) + (n-1)^3 + n^3

= T(n-3) + (n-2)^3 + (n-1)^3 + n^3

.....        ......       ........

= T(0) + 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + ....... + (n-2)^3 + (n-1)^3 + n^3

= 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + ....... + (n-2)^3 + (n-1)^3 + n^3

= [image]

=  **O(n^4)**

We can tell its O(n^4) because once we solve it we will ignore all constants and variable with lower exponents in the equation and n^4 would have been the highest power of n.

Just in case if you heard of master theorem for solving recurrence relation.  And wondering how to use that for finding time complexity for this case. You can't because it not in form  of `T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)`.

It may work if you are able to somehow convert it in that form. Not the best option because we already have well known identity to use in this case. Master Theorem is a tool not a liability, use it where you can, otherwise use the best fit method.

Comment: Wouldn't the function be like n^4+(n-1)^4+(n-2)^4+(n-3)^4+...1 ? Because of n is decrementing one by one(when calling method) and each n value running in hello method. So if (n*(n+1)/2)^4 formula get used, and wouldn't result be like O(n^8)?

Comment: @user8342837 ohh Sorry mate didn't notice it, New solution should be right.

Comment: Thank you for your interest bro. But according to Master theorem rules, I found a=1,b=(-1) and d=3. So, theorem's result of T(n)=T(n-1)+n^3 is not equal to O(n^4). [a>(b)^d ---> 1>(-1)^3 so n^(logba (based b)). If I didn't misunderstand, you took 2nd power of (n*(n+1)/2) but shouldn't we take 3rd power of (n*(n+1)/2)?

Comment: @user8342837 TO solve it using masters theorem you have to write in the form of T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n). But here it not in that form, Don't confuse T(n) = T(n-1) + n^3 with that form. here we  have (n-1) in place of n/b. you have to further derive the equation in that form.

Comment: @user8342837 In T(n) = T(n-1) + n^3  , b does not exist.

Comment: Right bro, my bad. I was confused. Time was night in my country but I was still working so I was distracted, I could not notice. But I understand now.  Thank you for answer bro.